# The reason for not displaying dialogue in activity

Tags: android

I'm using a method written in a class and using it in the program I wrote, I can display a dialog on the page when the GPS is turned off or on.
My problem is that this dialog is displayed correctly in an activity, but in another activity, the dialog box is encountered with error and the program is closed.

error message:

```
2019-02-23 11:33:04.211 7855-7871/com.uncocoder.course.app.database E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
2019-02-23 11:33:25.764 7855-7855/com.uncocoder.course.app.database E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.uncocoder.course.app.database, PID: 7855
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@b74def8 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:678)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
    at com.uncocoder.course.app.database.GPSTracker.showSettingsAlert(GPSTracker.java:125)
    at com.uncocoder.course.app.database.GPSTracker.onProviderDisabled(GPSTracker.java:142)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:310)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.-wrap0(LocationManager.java)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:242)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

My GPSTracker Class:

```
    public class GPSTracker implements LocationListener {
public static double x, y;
private final Context mContext;
public int code = 0;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alert;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;

Location location;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled) {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }

            if (isGPSEnabled && location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.Alert_Title);
    TextView txt_comment_dialog = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_comment_dialog);
    ImageButton imageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.Alert_Image);
    title.setText("plz turn on GPS");
    txt_comment_dialog.setText("error GPS");
    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.location_off);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setView(view);
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    code = 1;

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String str = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
    x = location.getLatitude();
    y = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    if (code == 0) {
        showSettingsAlert();
    }

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    if (code == 1) {

        alert.dismiss();
        code = 0;
    } else {
        code = 0;
    }

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}
```

Comment: Hello.
I have a question about the code I wrote on Android Studio.

Comment: did you add permisson and runtime permisson??

Comment: did you add activity in manifest file

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

Comment: I added these permissions to the manifesto

Comment: In the activity login and if the GPS is turned off, the dialog will be displayed and closed when the dialog is turned on.
The problem is that in the next activity, if the GPS is turned off, the dialog will not be displayed and the program will issue an error message and exit the application.

Comment: While there is no problem login in to Activity !!

Comment: please guide me

Comment: how do you implement this class in your activities?

Comment: You do not need to call this class and it works automatically.

Comment: I think it works as a BroadCastReceiver